# Yes or No as result of sql query without IF or CASE usage

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to make a query and return 'yes' or 'no' as an answer without the use of Flow Control operators?

The only solution I thought is:

```
select 'yes' as answer 
from blabla
where blabla
```

but this of course works only if the query found some results.

Comment: Just `select 'yes';`?

Comment: Add some more context. Otherwise, Phylogenesis' answer is absolutely valid.

Comment: I have a db with students, schools, teachers etc.. and i want to see if a kid with a specific name exists in this school. Return yes if he exists or no if he doesn't.

Comment: Why `id` is bad result? why do you need replace some real data with `yes` placeholder on the mysql  query level?

Comment: @pirox22: Don't do something like that in a SQL query. Just make a query for a student with the name in question. If it returns one or more rows, it's a "yes", otherwise a "no". It just makes no sense to do what you describe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like your `blabla` but don't understand your goal.

What is wrong with `IF()` statement or `CASE WHEN ELSE END`?

If you like your `blabla` code you can continue the same logic:

```
select 'yes' as answer 
from blabla
where blabla.column=1
UNION
select 'no' as answer 
from blabla
where blabla.column<>1
```

and here is another tricky solution:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76065/24

```
SELECT @answer
FROM (
  SELECT @answer:='yes' 
  FROM blabla
  WHERE blabla.id=5
) y
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT @answer:='no') n
ON 1;
```

Comment: +1 for a valid solution. However, I would add a remark that it's not good practice unless OP comes up with more context.

Comment: Absolutely agree with you. Answer like this should be downvoted. Same as the question. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to `COALESCE`:

```
select coalesce(
    select 'yes' as answer 
    from blablaT
    where blabla,
    select 'no' as answer 
    from blablaT
    where not blabla) as result from dual;
```